# Facing difficulties while framing sentences

Tags: meaning

I do face difficulties while using following sentences. Could you please someone explain me the difference between these. Are these sentences give same meaning?

> What you have done if you were in my place.
>   What have you done if were you in my place?

Comment: The difficulty you're having may be because the verb needs *would* (because of the conditional), "What would you have done..." and "if were you" is ungrammatical. I think you'll get the best answer from our sister site.

Answer (score 1):

No, they are not equivalent.

Leaving aside issues of grammar, the first is a noun phrase and the second is a question.

By way of analogy, the first is to "Praveen M P" as the second is to "What is your name?"

Comment: Thank you. I need to change the sentence to .. What would you have done if were you in my place? is this correct?.

Comment: No it doesn't. You can't have "if were you". "What would you have done if you were in my place?" is correct; although, depending on context, "if you had been in my place" might be better.

Comment: Or, simply omit *if*: What would you have done, were you in my place.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to say is, "What would you have done if you were in my place?"

If you want to make a statement, you would say, "This is what you would have done if you were in my place" or "You would have done the same thing if you were in my place."